# Laravel Livewire wire:navigate issues with flowbite

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire, flowbite

I am trying to use flowbite (Drawer, but I am guessing same will be true for all of them) components in my Laravel & Livewire application, but I keep experiencing issues where the drawer does not work after I `wire:navigate` to a new page.

When I remote `wire:navigate` from the link tags, everything works fine, but I'd like to take advantage of that SPA routing behaviour

In my `resources/js/app.js` file, I have the following:

```
document.addEventListener("livewire:navigated", () => {
    initFlowbite();
});
```

And when I navigate, I get the following error:

```
flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2961 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove')
    at Drawer2._destroyBackdropEl (flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2961:52)
    at Drawer2.destroy (flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2869:14)
    at Drawer2.destroyAndRemoveInstance (flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2878:12)
    at Instances2.addInstance (flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:60:40)
    at new Drawer2 (flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2845:25)
    at flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:3039:7
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at initDrawers (flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:3030:53)
    at initFlowbite (flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:4082:3)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:6:5)
Drawer2._destroyBackdropEl @ flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2961
Drawer2.destroy @ flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2869
Drawer2.destroyAndRemoveInstance @ flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2878
Instances2.addInstance @ flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:60
Drawer2 @ flowbite.js?v=931fd44c:2845
```

From the browser's console, clicking on the file link, I see:

```
Drawer2.prototype._destroyBackdropEl = function() {
      if (this._visible) {
        document.querySelector("[drawer-backdrop]").remove();
      }
    };
```

logging `document.querySelector("[drawer-backdrop]")` returns `null`

How do I go about fixing this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I was able to come up with in my case, was to do the following:

```
document.addEventListener("livewire:navigating", () => {
    // Mutate the HTML before the page is navigated away...
    initFlowbite();
});

document.addEventListener("livewire:navigated", () => {
    // Reinitialize Flowbite components
    initFlowbite();
});
```

The other option was to try and loop through the nested objects returned by calling `FlowbiteInstances.getAllInstances()`, but that is more tedious and using nested loops is usually not my favourite thing to do.

Hope this helps someone and hope a better solution is released soon, if any.

Thanks.